# How to add whitelisted domains when using Safari Content blocker in the iPhone

Tags: ios, safari-extension, ios-extensions, safari-content-blocker

What's the proper way to create whitelists when using Safari content blocker API?
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ContentBlocker.html

Imagine I have an adult content blocker like this one, but instead of 3 domains, 50000. (I already did it and it works)

```
[
    {
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "trigger": {
            "url-filter": ".*",
            "if-domain": ["*xvideos.com", "*pornhub.com", "*xxx.com"]
        }
    }
]
```

How should I add a whitelist?
Do I have to create a second blocker with other rules or do I have to modify my adult content blocker to remove the whitelisted domains programmatically in real time, generate another JSON and reloading it?

Answer (score 2):

You start by blocking everything:

```
{
    "action": {
        "type": "block"
    },
        "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*"
    }
}
```

than you whitelist (for example) the website "Google.com":

```
{
    "action": {
        "type": "ignore-previous-rules"
    },
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": "Google.com/.*"
    }
}
```

Here I approve "Google.com" and everything down his hierarchy, for example "Google.com/shop" or "Google.com/account".

**Edit**:
it seems I was wrong, and not the first one to fall into it, to white list a website, This is how it's done:

```
{
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*",
        "if-domain": ["Google.com"]
    },
    "action": {
        "type": "ignore-previous-rules"
    } 
}
```

You can see full list of commands here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker

Also check this question:
[iOS Content Blocker Whitelist Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975416/ios-content-blocker-whitelist-website)